# Laravel redirect dilemma after login

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In route i have group of route , that are protected with filter backend_login

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend', 'before' => 'backend_auth'), function() {

    Route::get('/','AdminMainController@index');
    Route::get('/main', 'AdminMainController@index');
    Route::get('/logout', 'UserMainController');
});


Route::any('backend/login', array('as' => 'backend_login', 'uses' =>'AdminUserController@login'));
```

in filter.php i have a filter

```
Route::filter('backend_auth', function(){
    if ( ! Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('backend_login');
});
```

The problem is when user is already loginned , he can still go back to login page. I tried to prevent it by adding to filter 'backend_auth'

```
Route::filter('backend_auth', function(){
    if ( ! Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('backend_login');
    else {
         return Redirect::to('backend/main');
    }
});
```

But then i got an redirect loop. Actually , redirecting to backend/main after login is what i want, but i can't make it work properly.
Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Check the filter is being called. If not check the environment you are using, as filters within the testing env are disabled by default.

Comment: sorry, but i dont really understand what you want to say.

Comment: Check with dd('Testing'); within your filter it is being called. If it is not being called then the environment that laravel is using, (i.e. local, production, or testing etc) could be set to testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
In the filter.php i just have to check if the user is loginned, to show him login page. Then in the start of login function in AdminUserController, i will decide if i want to redirect him to backend/main or not. So the problem with infinite redirect loop would be solved.

```
  if (Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('backend_main');
```